# "Right to left" order of different directioned spans

Tags: html, css, arabic, right-to-left

I have the following html:

```html
<div dir="rtl">
    <span>"arabic 1"</span>
    <span>"عربي 2"</span>
    <span>"arabic 3"</span>
    <span>"arabic 4"</span>
</div>
```

All I am trying to do is to make those `spans` appear in the same order they are from right to left because they are mainly containing Arabic text, but also possibly any other language..

I prefer CSS solutions to html attributes (for more flexibility)

Comment: Just float the spans to the right?

Comment: Okay, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: @user1415571, You will notice that with my code the spans will come in this order: (1, 2, 4, 3). I was asking about the best way to solve this and make them appear in the right order (1, 2, 3, 4).

I figured out "float: right" is the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `span` element has by default the value `normal` for the [`unicode-bidi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) property. This means, in effect, that consecutive `span` elements are treated as one unit in bidirectional formatting. In the example case, the last two `span` elements contain just Latin letters, spaces, digits, and Ascii quotation marks, so they will be treated as one string `"arabic 3" "arabic 4"`, which will thus be rendered left to right.

If you set `unicode-bidi: embed` on the `span` elements, they will be treated as units laid according to the layout direction set by the `direction` property (which is implicitly set by the HTML `dir` attribute) of their parent.

```html
<style>
span { unicode-bidi: embed; }
</style>
<div dir="rtl">
<span>"arabic 1"</span>
<span>"عربي 2"</span>
<span>"arabic 3"</span>
<span>"arabic 4"</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this solution is better than using "float" because it's language and direction independent

Answer (score 1):

Using flexboxes, you could set the display of the parent element to `flex`, and then add `flex-direction: row-reverse` to reverse the order of the elements;

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>"arabic 1"</span>
    <span>"عربي 2"</span>
    <span>"arabic 3"</span>
    <span>"arabic 4"</span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, in some cases, you may also be able to float the elements to the right:

```css
.parent span {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>"arabic 1"</span>
    <span>"عربي 2"</span>
    <span>"arabic 3"</span>
    <span>"arabic 4"</span>
</div>
```

It's also worth pointing out that there is a `direction` property, too. You could set the value to `rtl`... but that's the same as the `direction="rtl"` attribute that you had.

```css
.parent {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>"arabic 1"</span>
  <span>"عربي 2"</span>
  <span>"arabic 3"</span>
  <span>"arabic 4"</span>
</div>
```